# Direct3D - Get screen coordinates for printing multiple text elements

Tags: directx, vector, screen, text

I have a function that I use to print text `PrintText(char* text)` that stores the text to a vector, which is then displayed if the vector is not empty. I'm trying to figure out how can I correctly print multiple char* to the screen, one under the next?

For example:
This is line one.
This is line two.

Both of those are stored in separate char* elements in the vector. How can I use Direct3D or C++ to correctly display consecutive char* elements as it is in the above example? As in getting the correct screen coordinates to display the next element?

Code:

```
void DrawString(char* String, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, ID3DXFont* ifont)
{
    RECT ShadowPos;
    ShadowPos.left = x + 1;
    ShadowPos.top = y + 1;
    RECT FontPos;
    FontPos.left = x;
    FontPos.top = y;
    ifont->DrawTextA(0, String, strlen(String), &ShadowPos, DT_NOCLIP, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, r / 3, g / 3, b / 3));
    ifont->DrawTextA(0, String, strlen(String), &FontPos, DT_NOCLIP, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, r, g, b));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I haven't fully coded it yet, but I have an idea of how to do it. But I'm also stuck when it comes to using a text wrap and the one element uses two lines because of the text wrap restriction.

Comment: Do you have code that can render a single string?

Comment: Yes, I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for [`DrawTextA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173962(v=vs.85).aspx), *"the return value is the height of the text in logical units"*.  So you should modify your `DrawString` function to return this value (plus one, since you draw the shadow one pixel lower).  You'd then offset the calling function's `y`-coordinate by the returned value, plus whatever padding you want.  So something like this:

```
void DrawString(char* String, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, ID3DXFont* ifont)
{
    RECT ShadowPos;
    ShadowPos.left = x + 1;
    ShadowPos.top = y + 1;
    RECT FontPos;
    FontPos.left = x;
    FontPos.top = y;
    ifont->DrawTextA(0, String, strlen(String), &ShadowPos, DT_NOCLIP, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, r / 3, g / 3, b / 3));
    int h = ifont->DrawTextA(0, String, strlen(String), &FontPos, DT_NOCLIP, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, r, g, b));
    return h + 1;
}

...

int y = 0, h = 0, padding = 4;
for(auto& s : vStrings)
{
    h = DrawString(s.c_str(), 0, y, ...);
    y += h + padding;
}
```